# Eclipse e4 application does not start in Java Web start

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, java-web-start, e4

I have written an Eclipse E4 application. Now we need to publish this to the users with Java Web Start. I found a "how to" on the [Eclipse website](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjava_web_start.htm). The project has been exported correctly (signed and jnlp files are created). Now when I start the application using Web Start everything looks good until the application itself need to start. No errors are given and nothing can be found in the Web Start logs.

This is the JNLP main page that we use:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp 
    spec="1.0+" 
    codebase="http://localhost:80" 
    href="test.jnlp"> <!-- URL to the site containing the jnlp application. It should match the value used on  export. Href, the name of this file -->
  <information>
    <!-- user readable name of the application -->
    <title> Test Application </title>  
    <!-- vendor name -->
    <vendor>My company</vendor>
    <!-- vendor homepage --> 
    <homepage href="My company website" /> 
    <!-- product description -->
    <description></description> 
    <icon kind="splash" href="splash.gif"/>
  </information>

  <!--request all permissions from the application. This does not change-->
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>

  <!-- The name of the main class to execute. This does not change-->
  <application-desc main-class="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WebStartMain">
    <argument>-nosplash</argument>
  </application-desc>

  <resources>
    <!-- Reference to the launcher jar. The version segment must be updated to the version being used-->
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417.jar"/>

    <!-- Reference to all the plugins and features constituting the application -->
    <!-- Here we are referring to the wrapper feature since it transitively refers to all the other plug-ins  necessary -->
    <extension 
        name="Wrapper feature"
        href="features/CR_IT_Client_Feature_1.0.0.201608230817.jnlp"/>

    <!-- Information usually specified in the config.ini -->

    <!-- The id of the product to run, like found in the overview page of the product editor -->
    <property 
        name="eclipse.product" 
        value="CR-IT System Platform.product"/>
  </resources>

  <!-- Indicate on a platform basis which JRE to use --> 
  <resources os="Mac">
    <j2se version="1.5+" java-vm-args="-XstartOnFirstThread"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows">
    <j2se version="1.4+"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Linux">
    <j2se version="1.4+"/>
  </resources>
</jnlp>
```

I did some researched and did found a log file of web start.
In the log there you can find the error: "Missing Permissions manifest attribute in main jar: http://localhost:80/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar". My manifest file looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Permissions: all-permissions
Application-Name: CR-IT System Platform
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: CR-IT System Platform
Bundle-SymbolicName: CR-IT_client;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.ac.client.eclipse.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: AC
Require-Bundle: javax.inject;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 org.eclipse.core.runtime;bundle-version="3.11.1",
 org.eclipse.swt;bundle-version="3.104.2",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench;bundle-version="1.1.100",
 org.eclipse.jface;bundle-version="3.11.1",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.services;bundle-version="1.2.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench;bundle-version="1.3.1",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.di;bundle-version="1.5.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.di;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts;bundle-version="1.4.0",
 org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.pshelf;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher;bundle-version="1.3.100",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.services;bundle-version="2.0.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.tools.css.spy;bundle-version="0.12.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 swing2swt.jar,
 libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar,
 libs/gettext-commons-0.9.8.jar,
 libs/java_websocket.jar
```

Does someone know a sollution for this strange issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the manefest file inside the jar. This by doing jar -ufm

The changes that I added are:
Permissions: all-permissions

```
Codebase: *
Application-Name: <<App name>>
Trusted-Only: true
Trusted-Library: true
```